# orientdb matching multiple possible edges

Tags: match, orientdb

I am currently investigating using OrientDB to implement an authorisation system and I'm having some trouble with the edge arrow notation.

The graph has four different vertex types:

- User
- Group
- Role
- Resource

And four different edge types:

- IN_GROUP
- HAS_ROLE
- CAN_ACCESS
- INHERITS

And the structure is:

- User -IN_GROUP-> Group
- Group -HAS_ROLE-> Role
- Role -CAN_ACCESS-> Resource
- Role -INHERITS-> Role

A role may inherit other roles. This means that Role A may inherit Role B which may inherit Role C. I want to produce an Orient query that can say 'For a specific user, give me all of their roles, including any that they inherit'

Currently to get a roles inherited roles I'm doing this but it only retrieves the first level of inherited nodes:

`match {class:User, where:(name='Sean')} -IN_GROUP-> {class:Group} -HAS_ROLE-> {} -INHERITS-> {class:Role, as:role} return role.name`

What I'm trying to retrieve is the entire chain of nodes that this initial role inherits, can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

what you need here is a WHILE condition on the INHERITS relationship:

```
 match 
    {class:User, where:(name='Sean')} -IN_GROUP-> 
    {class:Group} -HAS_ROLE-> {} -INHERITS-> {class:Role, as:role, while:(true)} 
 return role.name
```